# Is it possible to have "folders" in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, directory

I am going to have a database with several (less than 10) "main" tables. Additionally to that I want to have hundreds or thousands tables of the same type (let same "user_1", "user_2", "user_3" and so on). Is it possible to put all these tables in a directory/folder? Or database itself is already considered as a "folder" for tables?

**ADDED**

Since I go a lot of questions about why I want to do that, I want to elaborate on that. I want to have many tables to optimize query to the database. If I put everything in one table, the table is going to be huge. Than, if I want to extract information about a particular user, I first need to find those rows in the table which have a given user in a given column. And it can be time consuming. I decided to create a table for every user. So, if I need to know something about a user I just read the required information from a "small" table.

To be more specific, I can have 10 000 user and information about a given user can contain 10 000 lines. I do not want to have one table with 100 000 000 lines.

Comment: If you are actually following your example of individual tables for each user such as `user_1`, you shouldn't do this (tables should really be fixed, and ideally, shouldn't change dynamically); add a column to a data table specifying the user that the data relates to.

Comment: I would be interested to know why you even want to have a separate table for each user... x)

Comment: This has got to be one of the strangest questions I have ever seen. Why you would even consider a table per user, is beyond me. Perhaps you could elaborate....

Comment: Why are you trying to optimise queries to the database before you even have a database? A lot of frighteningly clever people have put many man-years of effort into making databases pretty good at efficiently storing and querying the data they hold; I don't think your example of 10,000 users would cause even a comparative "lightweight" DB to break a sweat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is—you shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Don't have separate tables for each user—instead, use one table for all your user data, and add a column (e.g. `userId`) to store information on who it's about.

Comment: +1 Indexing on UserID should ensure performance is satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want separate tables based on the user, this tends to be done using an `owner` or `schema` concept. In other words, you use:

```
create table pax.table1 ...
```

and pax is them the owner of that table. Each user can then have their own data.

If you don't mind everyone seeing the data in each others "folders", you can opt for a single table with a column specifying the particular user but you tend to lose user-based protection in that case.

Having each user's data in their own schema (or owner) means that you can restrict access based on user name. Keep in mind that these are then *separate* tables so it becomes harder to consolidate data from them should you wish to do so.

It's pretty unusual to have hundreds of thousands of tables, even in the biggest database setups. You might want to consider the possibility that you're doing something unwise. Posting the "why" of this question instead of the "how" will help us in assisting you further.